# CSS Gradient in IE8 Disables my Dropdown menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Website in question: http://atlanticsig.creativecurvedev2.ca/

A little background... This is a development site for a client that I am building in MODx using the Wayfinder extension for the menu and Ultimate Dropdown for the sub-menu. I am using CSS gradients to produce the pretty background color for the menu.

My issue is that in IE8, the drop-down menu does not display for the header navigation when I incorporate a "filter" gradient background color. Only the IE8 browser has this issue; even IE7 works properly. The drop-down menu is there, technically, because the cursor can click on the sub-menu links, but the browser refuses to show them.

I have fixed the issue by using a repeated background image for IE8, but I really didn't want to go this route; I thought for sure there should be a CSS solution, which is why I am posting this; my curiosity is piqued and I would like to see what the real issue was.

I was able to track down the issue to this line of code:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

As soon as I removed this line from the following block of code, the drop-down menu would work fine in IE8, however the gradient would disappear:

```
#header_menu {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #003764 0%, #3b6b89 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#003764), color-stop(100%,#3b6b89)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #003764 0%,#3b6b89 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #003764 0%,#3b6b89 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #003764 0%,#3b6b89 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #003764 0%,#3b6b89 100%); /* W3C */
background-color: #003764; /* Old browsers */
height: 38px;
width: auto;
}
```

I tried a number of fixes in the HTML and CSS, including various arrangements of the gradients, applying the gradients to different elements, applying various heights/widths/position values to my containers and menus, playing with z-index values, adding extra  blocks, etc.

In the end, it always seemed to come back to that "filter" line (I even tried -ms-filter-).

If you would like snippets of any other pieces of code, just let me know. This is a pretty interesting issue that I has made me genuinely curious to solve.

Comment: yea that filter line is really buggy, better off using an image

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, using IE's `filter` style is always asking for trouble -- it has a whole load of bugs and quirks that can break other stuff unexpectedly.

So what are your options?

- You could try using CSS3Pie to render your gradients. It uses VML rather than filters, so it won't suffer from the same bugs. (or you could write the VML code yourself, but that would be tedious)
- Or you could use a graphic for the gradient in IE8. You could arrange the CSS code such that the standard CSS gradient overrides the background graphic, so other browsers could carry on using the CSS gradient and wouldn't need to know about the graphic.
- Or you could just accept that IE8 is an old browser and give it a plain background rather than a gradient. It may not look as pretty but it'll still work, and people still using IE8 are probably used to seeing sites these days that don't look their best.